# How do I change the output from being 1,2,3,4,5 to being first, second, etc.?

Tags: c++

How do I get my output to change from saying 1,2,3,4,5 to stating first, second, third, fourth, fifth? Also, at the end when it declares which input is the minimum, how do I get it to say whether it was entry 1-5, not the actual input number?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
int num[5];
int i = 0;
int small=0;

    cout <<"Enter the first number: ";
    cin >> num[0];
    small = num[0];
    {
        for(i = 1; i < 5; i++) 
            {
             cout << "Enter the number "<< i + 1 <<" number: ";
             cin >> num[i];
                if (num[i] < small)         
                    small = num[i];
            }
    }
cout<<endl<<endl;   
cout<<"Entry No. "<<small<<" is the minimum number"<<endl<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's `i` inside the loop you're looking for, so find a way to save it and make it accessible outside the loop.

Comment: @GermaineJason You can't mix types like that in an array.

Comment: @BlueIce sorry noob mistake!

Comment: @BenVoigt - I don't really know how to do that, that's the problem. I have a functional program, I just don't know how to change small details.

Comment: @GermaineJason is there an easier way that doesn't involve arrays or vectors? We haven't covered that material in the class that I am in. I am in the beginners C++ course. It's probably a good thing programming isn't my major...I don't think I'd be very good at it. I commend you guys.

Comment: @germaineJason No problem! Don't worry about making mistakes- other people just want to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

You want to not only find the smallest `num[i]`, but also the corresponding `i`.  That's straightforward.  The key will be to replace the guts of the loop

```
if (num[i] < small)         
    small = num[i];
```

with

```
if (num[i] < small) {    // when num[i] is the smallest so far
    small = num[i];      //     save it
    smalli = i;          //     and save the matching i
}
```

I suspect you can figure out the variable declaration and initial value.

To print a cardinal word, you can use

```
const char* cardinals[] = { "first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth" };
```

and then display `cardinals[i]` in your prompt.  And/or `cardinals[smalli]` at the end.

```
std::cout << "\n\nThe " << cardinals[smalli] " number was the minimum, " << small << "\n\n";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 5;

    const char *serial_num[N] = { 'first", "second", "third", "fourth", "fifth" };
    int num[N];

    size_t small;

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < N; i++ ) 
    {
        std::cout << "Enter the " << serial_num[i] << " number: ";
        std::cin >> num[i];

        if ( i == 0 || num[i] < num[small] ) small = i;
    }   

    std::cout << "\n\nEntry No. " << serial_num[small] << " is the minimum number\n" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```